# DIV moves when other div gets bigger

Tags: html, css

When I hover over a link the text gets larger, I have two divs next to each other and when I hover over the longest link on the left div the right div moves to the right.
How do I fix this?

```
#social{
    font-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding:5px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: some more html source code and css would be useful as your images don't really show a distinguishable difference other than the color change

Comment: Please share a live example : http://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute`, by using this the second menu will not be dependent on the first one for its positioning and will stay where you position it with `top` and `left`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the CSS of the link

```
a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

you can also edit in that everything that happens with the hover, so font size, colour etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of you can decide how the links should look when hovering on them by using the :hover selector. Example:

```
a:hover {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Now, what's causing the other div to move is the fact that the link gets bigger. It looks like your hovering effect is making the link text **bold**. Try removing that, as it's a real pain to work around. if you need to override it:

```
a:hover {
    font-weight: normal; // Add !imporant after 'normal' if nothing happens.
}
```

Comment: I wan't the text to get bigger but I want it to not effect the other div.

Comment: I really recommend you to find another way to highlight the text. Making the text bigger WILL make the element take up more space. I've faced this issue as well, and it resulted in me completely ditching that idea.

Comment: If you ABSOLUTELY must, try wrapping the links in a div, set those divs to a maximum width (or set width: 100% if the column has a set width). And then, give those divs overflow-x: hidden. Best thing that comes to mind, might require a few modifications though as I don't really have time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the default layout of `div`, when the link that you are hovering on changes size, it will "push" the `div` next to it in order to accommodate the larger text. The easiest thing to do is not enlarge the text when it is hovered over since this moves page elements. Otherwise, you can also manually define the position of the second `div` using CSS (`position` with a combination of `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with two things. Floating it left will mean that the moment that the maximum width of any element to the left of it resizes, than all divs to the right will either move over to accommodate, or drop down below if there is no room in the viewport to the right. Therefore, when you hover over with text effects, it will do as you described.

Next is you probably have some CSS conflicts causing it to get big when you hover. Just as everyone else has said already, adjusting in CSS with the anchor tag will probably solve your issue.

```
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: inherit;
}
```

That should fix your problem, otherwise remove font-size: inherit and you'll be okay.